# How can I change the number of the row using “show 10/25/50/100/All entries” in Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I want to change the number of the row depends on the options I select. For example, I choose 25 in my select I want to display all the rows on my table. This is the value I put on my select 10/25/50/100/All when I choose it automatically changes the number of rows and "Showing N to N of N entries". How can I do that? Can somebody help me with my problem? Here's my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rgka8m01/17/

```
 showEntries: function() {
    if (value == 10) {
        return Math.ceil(this.categories.length / this.perPage)
    } else if (value == 25) {
        return Math.ceil(this.categories.length / 25)
    } else if (value == 50) {
        return Math.ceil(this.categories.length / 50)
    } else if (value == 100) {
        return Math.ceil(this.categories.length / 100)
    } else if (value == 'All') {
        return Math.ceil(this.categories.length / 1000)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i mutated your code and commented the mutations above each line check this sample https://jsfiddle.net/0hn1dsc7/ and tell me if that's what you want

```
showEntries: function(value) {
 this.endIndex = value;
 }
```

Comment: sir how about the pagination? I want to change it also depends on the row I have. For example, I have 10 rows the pagination will look like this Previous 1 Next then if I have 50 rows the pagination will look like this Previous 123 Next